# Chrome Developer Tools: changing the scale of timeline grpah

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to learn how to use the Network Tab in Chrome Developer Tools. 
Here is a screenshot of the Network tab:

[image]

As you can see, in the right side of the image there is a timeline graph. The graph ends at 1 second, although the "longest" event takes 11 ms. I want to change the scale of the graph that it'll end at 20 ms. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Use mouse selection and mouse wheel to zoom over horizontal minigraph *above* the details table.

Comment: I think the OP's question was, not how do I scope to only the events within a small timeframe, but how do I zoom in on the timeline so that you see that small timeframe expand to the left and right sides of the window.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The mouse wheel changes the selection in the overview (a.k.a. "minigraph above"), depending on where the cursor is located. Usually, scrolling up seems to pull the selection closer to the cursor and/or make the selection smaller, but it is not very consistent. Could not figure out a way to actually zoom though. Navigating the timeline in "Performance insights" tab works differently.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a visual guide for @wOxxOm comment:

[image: Scaling Network]